# Is it possible to retrieve Elastic IP address with boto only using IAM user credentials?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto, elastic-ip

Having created a boto connection with IAM user credentials, I'm not able to get Elastic IPs are being allocated by the same user:

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(region, **iam_user_only_credentials)
addresses = con.get_all_addresses(filters={'public_ip': "my EIP address"})
# addresses array is empty here
```

Are Elastic IP addresses only associated to root credentials (AWS root credentials)? Is it possible to associate them to a user? (as mine was created being myself an IAM user -- w/ pretty much full access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree. It appears that `boto2` does not return addresses as documented.

Fortunately, it does function in `boto3`:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.describe_addresses(Filters=[{'Name':'public-ip','Values':['54.XX.XX.XX']}])
```